# Can there be a separate site for "off-topic" Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, split-stack-overflow

It seems a lot of questions on Stack Overflow are considered off topic but still hold valuable information. For example, a lot of questions like [Recommended Java maths/stats library [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740602/recommended-java-maths-stats-library) are closed because they focus on resources instead of the actual programming language.

What if instead of being closed down, they were simply migrated to another site on the Stack Exchange network or a subdomain of Stack Overflow specifically for these types of questions?

---

I recognize that many questions that I linked to are regarded as not a fit by the mods. I know better than to suggest changing that. My main reason for inquiring is that, despite such questions not being an ideal fit for Stack Overflow, I still think they are valuable information, and I think closing them to discussion has drawbacks. Thus the motive for creating a separate area for them.

Clearly others do not think so, but I am interested in knowing why. I've read through several of the other questions along these lines and didn't really find a definite conclusion to the issue. I don't mind the negative votes, but I honestly would be interested to know why.

Comment: By opening a question like this here, pointing to a question like that, you'll end up getting those who like to purge the site riled and start the deletion process for that question.  Stack Exchange has some large questions on this topic.

Comment: Something along these lines? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99467

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be

Comment: [Here's one post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: This comes up *a lot*. Please take a little time to search through meta and read questions from all the other people with the same idea.

Comment: Relevant: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related

Comment: Relevant: I still have stackoverflowoverflow.com if someone is willing to make such a thing.

Comment: _@theguywiththeface_ _"Owch, -8 votes in less than half an hour."_ Downvotes at meta merely address disagreement, rather than indicating a bad question (especially if you use the [tag:feature-request] tag).

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 4):

We maybe could provide a SO BIN site (Name proposal for Area51 *"Stack Overflow Junk Pile"*), where the beggars could poke around at all the junk we've removed from the official sites (and maybe even learn, why it was removed).

Read only of course (including comments). You could just think about it like a zoo, where you can watch all of these exotic animals alive.

Upvotes may count for frequency watched, downvotes may be for overall low recognition (not sure).

That site's only purpose is to automatically receive any closed/deleted question migrated to it, and it appears at the top of the proposed migration sites for any other established SE site.

**Note:**
I'm not going to propose such counter SE site for SE StackOverflow at Area51, but anyone inspired by this trigger may try.

---

<sub>Before you downvote this answer, switch on your *sense of satire/sarcasm* please!</sub>

Comment: Are you sure I have a sense of satire/sarcasm? Cannot find it.

Comment: @Deduplicator Most of the people not categorized as _psychopathic_ have it. But _psychopathic_ people use their's to manipulate others ;-) ...

Comment: Could you explain the use of sarcasm? I don't understand where it is, and I'm actually being serious.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - leave me out of it:)

Comment: @TheGuyWithTheFace Sarcasm, and satire are _serious_ instruments introducing some humor. I made a proposal you could follow, but I seriously doubt, it would fly well from Area51.

Comment: @MartinJames Did I invite you personally at any point?

Comment: On a serious note, this is sort of the "SO Acadmey" idea which was shot down in favor of people asking how to improve specific posts on Meta. Granted, it wasn't intended to help with off-topic posts.

Answer (score 3):

*What if instead of being closed down, they were simply migrated to another site on the StackExchange network or a subdomain of stackoverflow specifically for these types of questions?*

This feature already exists. There's already a flag for migrating a question instead of closing it. You can also leave a comment on the question telling the Asker which site they should have asked their question on if it isn't in the list. You just need to point them to the "What's on topic" page for that site, assuming they asked a good question in the first place. Mods do not appreciate you sending bad questions their way; IIRC, there was a Meta post about how "we don't migrate garbage".